# Deallocated in delegate paradigm

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have `ParentViewController` that allocates `ChildViewController`, pushes it onto controller stack and releases it.

`ChildViewController` implements the protocol `ProductDownloadDelegateProtocol` required by the Product class.

At some point, `ChildViewController` creates a Product object and sets itself as its `downloadDelegate`.

While downloading, `Product` class updates `ChildViewController` via methods defined in `ProductDownloadDelegateProtocol`.

If the user presses the back button in the navBar of `ChildViewController` while downloading, the next update of download percentage from `Product` causes an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.

Although `Product` checks if `downloadDelegate` is `nil`, problem still occurs since `ChildViewController/downloadDelegate` is deallocated, but not set as `nil`. I don't know which point is best to set `ChildViewController` to `nil`.

Is my design wrong?

Comment: This question is horrible to read. Btw : if you say you release something.... Don't you use ARC ?

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to explain it better. Nope, depending on old framework that wasn't updated.

Comment: Are you using ARC? That makes a big difference in what the correct answer is.

Comment: not using ARC in this project

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your `ChildViewController` creates an instance of `Product` and sets itself as the delegate, it should be its responsibility to remove itself as the delegate when it's about to be unloaded. Either in it's `viewDidUnload` or `dealloc` method you should be setting the `Product` delegate to nil.

If `ChildViewController` stays around (say you are reusing the view controller), maybe you can remove it as the delegate in the `viewWillDissappear` method.

Another solution to fix this particular EXC_BAD_ACCESS issue is to move to ARC and use Zeroing Weak References (see a good writeup here, http://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2010-07-16-zeroing-weak-references-in-objective-c.html).

Still, I would recommend you move to ARC for the right reasons, and not to fix this particular issue you are facing.

Comment: although I do not reuse view controller, removing itself seems to be too late when done from viewDidUnload, maybe just didn't investigate deep enough... I did it in viewWillDissapear, but explicit setting downloadDelegate seemed not to work, but calling Product method that sets it to nil itself worked. Will consider your suggestion on ARC, great answer, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

My rule of thumb goes like this: **You should never be the delegate of an object you do not own.** Here, "own" means "hold a strong reference to" (in ARC terms). The main exception is when the delegate retains you, and UIApplication.delegate because that's a bit weird.

Usually I bundle the logic into the setter like this:

```
-(void)setProduct:(Product*)p
{
  product.delegate = nil;
  [product release];
  product = [p retain];
  product.delegate = self;
}

-(void)dealloc
{
  self.product = nil;
}
```

However, an underlying problem with this design is that a "product download" can only have one delegate. What if you navigate away from the `ChildViewController` and then back into (a new instance of) it? Are they different `Product` instances, both being downloaded?

A better way might be to have a download manager singleton (as much as I hate singletons) that manages downloads and uses NSNotification/NSNotificationCenter for progress notifications.

Comment: You just made me have one of these "Oh snap!" moments with navigation back into ChildViewController. In my case, singleton isn't option here, my customer requires parallel product downloads. Product is subclass of NSManagedObject, so it's a nice little mess to clean out. Thanks for answer anyway.

Comment: I think you misunderstood: I was suggesting a singleton ProductDownloadManager which can download multiple Products.

Comment: That makes sense. Will consider it! thnx